# Plot bars in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I have a matrix(4,100) in MATLAB. Each one of its column are in such way that the 1st element 
matrix(1,i) is the smaller and the 4th element matrix(4,i) is the bigger. Something like

```
    matrix(:,1) = - 0.3; 0,4; 0,4; 0,9
```

How can I do a bar graph were I can plot as a bar the distance between the two edges?

each column has to be represented by on bar in order to make 100 bars at the end.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can plot all bars in different colors, from the largest (last row of `matrix`) to the smallest (first row of `matrix`), so that the smaller ones get stacked over but let the larger ones to be seen:

```
matrix = [.1 .2 .3 .4 .5
          .2 .3 .5 .6 .7
          .4 .4 .8 .7 .8
          .5 .6 .9 .8 .9]; %// example data
hold on
colors = {'r','g','b','c'}; %// define colors
for n = size(matrix,1):-1:1 %// iterate over rows, from last to first
    bar(matrix(n,:), colors{n})
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Luis actually I used your code and I and actually managed to  make the graph I wanted, though I have a question: I haven't understood what is the :-1:1 is doing in the "for" statement.

Comment: @Spyros That's looping over the row index from `size(matrix,1)` down to 1 with step size 1. Similar as `for (j = size(matrix,1); j >= 1; j--)` as in C.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by `edges` you mean the first and fourth element.

You can use:

```
diff = abs(matrix(1,:) - matrix(4,:)); // distance
bar(diff); // bar plot
```